# Finding specific hour minimum value using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this,

```
Date/Time               Volt        Current
2011-01-01 11:30:00     NaN         NaN
2011-01-01 11:35:00     NaN         NaN
2011-01-01 11:40:00     NaN         NaN
...
2011-01-01 12:30:00     NaN         NaN
2011-01-02 11:30:00     45          23
2011-01-02 11:35:00     31          34
2011-01-02 11:40:00     23          15
...
2011-01-02 12:30:00     13          1
2011-01-03 11:30:00     41          51
...
2011-01-03 12:25:00     14          5
2011-01-03 12:30:00     54          45
...
2011-01-04 11:30:00     45          -
2011-01-04 11:35:00     41          -
2011-01-04 11:40:00     -           4
...
2011-01-04 12:30:00     -           14
```

The dataframe has a date and time between 11:30:00 to 12:30:00 with a 5 minutes interval. I am trying to figure out how to find the minimum value based on the "Current" column for each day, and copy the entire row. My expected output should be something like this,

```
Date/Time               Volt        Current
2011-01-01              NaN         NaN
2011-01-02 12:30:00     13          1
2011-01-03 12:25:00     14          5
2011-01-04 11:40:00     NaN         4
```

For rows with a value in current, it will copy the entire minimum value row.
For rows with "NaN" in current, it will copy the row still with NaN.

Do note that some data in the volt/current are something empty or with a dash.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: very good question with neat explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```
df=df[df['Current'] != '-']
df.groupby(df['Date/Time'].dt.day).apply(lambda x:x.loc[x['Current'].astype(float).fillna(0).argmin(),:])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the line on my Python but I received "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ". Any idea? (Update: I realised I have entry with "-", is it possible to remove this dash as this is likely the problem.

Comment: Please post your dataframe with '-'

Comment: Hi pyd, I have edited my example in my original post. Thank you.

Comment: Do You want to remove rows which has '-'?

Comment: Hi pyd, it will not be easy to manually do it as there are more than 40k lines in the csv, this is why I am looking for a Python solution if possible. Thank you.